# circle progress bar plugin jquery that binds data from database

Tags: jquery, progress-bar, geometry

I want to place 3 circle progress bars in my project, but I don't want to show the progress there. Instead I want to show count of tasks, messages and events there (from Database). Any such plugin available, which can match my requirement.